# Getting the class labels from an sklearn.svm.LinearSVC object

Tags: python, scikit-learn

How can we get the class labels (e.g., ['business','lifestyle','sports','tech']) from a classifier object? The classifier method `predict` is able to produce the labels, so I guess it should be stored somewhere inside the classifier object.

I can't find it in the documentation (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html)

How to get the class labels?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a `classes_` field.

```
>>> from sklearn import svm
>>> clt = svm.SVC()
>>> clt.fit( [[1],[2],[3]], ["a","b","a"] )
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0, degree=3, gamma=0.0,
  kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=False, shrinking=True, tol=0.001,
  verbose=False)
>>> clt.classes_
array(['a', 'b'], 
      dtype='|S2')
```

Comment: Yes, I found it also. Thanks!
I wonder why didn't they put this into the documentation.

Comment: Actually they put it! But instead of having a separate entry for it, they put it as a change of `labels_` attribute

Answer (score 1):

I found it, it's hidden in the `classes_` attribute of the object.
Found it after reading the source code.